# objective-c why does nslog show strings inbetween double quotation marks " "?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nslog

I am loading a nsarray from a textfile:

```
NSArray *noWords = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
                        [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"untitled" ofType:@"txt"]
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
```

Untitled.txt contains:

```
alfa
beta (geologi).
beta
jaha
javel
jam (geologi) en
jamen
jamen
jamen
jax. (geologi)jammen
det
var
æhæhæ
øhøh
på
tide
.(geologi),be;ta;
tiden
men
but
men
aha
beta
```

NSLog (@"noWords : %@", noWords); shows:

```
2011-08-29 16:16:44.288 scanner2[30177:207] noWords : (
alfa,
"beta (geologi).",
beta,
jaha,
javel,
"jam (geologi) en",
jamen,
jamen,
jamen,
"jax. (geologi)jammen",
det,
var,
"\U00e6h\U00e6h\U00e6",
"\U00f8h\U00f8h",
"p\U00e5",
tide,
".(geologi),be;ta;",
tiden,
men,
but,
men,
aha,
beta
```

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/7227163/nslog-strange-behavior/7227275#7227275

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does that when there are spaces or other special characters in the string. Note that this is just what `NSLog()` does. When you do `[NSString stringWithFormat:...]` this doesn't happen.